# Get a list of database tables that contain a specific column field?

Tags: sql, postgresql

How to select all tables that contain a specific column?

Comment: What do you mean `a specific column`?

Comment: what does it mean select all tables and specific column ?could you please describe more

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you expect?

[demo: db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=6b812cb26632527273681df44f2c55ea)

```
SELECT table_name
FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE column_name = 'your_column_name'
```